# Bootstrap Rails : Custom Styles are not applied

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Hello in my Ruby on Rails Application i've installed the Bootstrap gems.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use less-rails for the twitter-bootstrap framework
gem 'less-rails'

# Use the twitter-bootstrap framework
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'


gem 'bootstrap-sass
```

I've created a view where the only element that i've inserted is a search bar where i've applied some standard style from boostrap and some custom style (search.scss).

This is the code of my view:

```
<% content_for :head do%>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'search.scss', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<% end %>


<!--Page Body-->
<div class="top-space"> <!--.top-space-->
    <div class="row"> <!--.row-->
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"><!--.col-->
        <h1 class="text-center">Ricerca un progetto</h1>
            <%= form_tag find_path,:class => 'input-group' ,:method => 'post' do%>
                <%=text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'form-control'%>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary",) do %>
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                  <% end %>
                </span>
            <% end %>
        </div> <!--.col-->
    </div> <!--.row-->
</div><!--.top-space -->
```

and this is my scss file:

```
//Global Attributes
html,
body{
    height: 100%;
    background: #f44336 !important;
}

//Research Bar
.top-space{
    padding-top: 50WS%;
}
.search-bar{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I don't know why but my custom style is not applied to the view of my application.

> PS: I know i can assign the style for the body in the file
>   bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less but i want to use it in one page only so i > write the body style rules in my custom css file